# Java Servlet to serving PDF but downloading as html in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, servlets

There is a Java Servlet that my angularJs 1.0 app is calling which sends data in PDF format I'm using the following to call the servlet

```
<a target="_self" download="my.pdf" ng-href="TheServlet">download</a>
```

When I click this link I get a file to download but it is always in the format of TheServlet.html

Changing the file extension to pdf on the downloaded document I can open and view the PDF just fine.  Looking for a way I can set the name of this dowloaded file to have a .pdf file extension.

Comment: the server should handle stuff like this

Comment: I have no control over this server